# Как сделать только одно слово в тексте жирным?

Tags: style, style-guide, textview

Нужно сделать несколько слов в тексте жирным?

Например нужно сделать так:
я **пошел** в магазин

еще хотелось бы узнать как сделать абзацы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я <b> пошёл </b> в магазин

Comment: спасибо, а вы не знаете еще как сделать отступы, то есть 
первая половина текста

вторая половина текста?

Comment: Перевод строки <br/>
<p>текст</p>новый абзац

Comment: не работает перевод строки:/

Comment: первая половина текста
<br><br>
вторая половина текста

Answer (score 0):

```
<p><strong>я пошел</strong> в магазин</p>
```